# Call function onPress React Native hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I just want to know how to write a `handleClick` function. I've setup my code like this:

```
const NoteContent = ({ note }) => {
    const [handle, setHandle] = useState({
        borderColor: 'blue', borderWidth: 1
    })

    const handleClick = () => {
        if (borderColor == "blue" && borderWidth == 1) {
            setHandle({ borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 2 })
        } else { ({ borderColor: "blue", borderWidth: 1}) }
    }


      <CardItem style={{ borderWidth: handle.borderWidth, borderColor: handle.borderColor }}>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleClick}>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: What is the behavior/error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare value from the object, so It's like `objectName.key` in your case `handle.borderColor`

---

You just have to write a function like,

```
const handleClick = () => {
    if (handle.borderColor == 'blue' && handle.borderWidth == 1) {
      setHandle({ borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 2 })
    } else { setHandle({ borderColor: 'blue', borderWidth: 1}) }
  }
```